# PHP PDO INSERT stop duplicate entry

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I need some assistance to get this code to work so that it prevents a duplicate entry into the database of the cname, ccode, crgeno and cvatno. Please help.

```
//My DB Code
public function insert($cname, $ccode, $cregno, $cvatno)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_client (ccode, cname, cregno, cvatno) VALUES (:amcname,:amccode,:amcregno,:amcvatno)";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['amcname' => $cname, 'amccode' => $ccode, 'amcregno' => $cregno, 'amcvatno' => $cvatno]);
        return true;
    }

//My action Code
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "insert"){
        $cname = $_POST['amcname'];
        $ccode = $_POST['amccode'];
        $cregno = $_POST['amcregno'];
        $cvatno = $_POST['amcvatno'];
        
        $db->insert($cname, $ccode, $cregno, $cvatno);
         
    }
```

@Simone:
So did this:

```
public function insert($cname, $ccode, $cregno, $cvatno)
    {

        $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT cname FROM tbl_client WHERE cname = ?");
        $query->bind_param('s',$cname);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();
        $count = $result->num_rows;

        if($count===0){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_client (ccode, cname, cregno, cvatno) VALUES (:amcname,:amccode,:amcregno,:amcvatno)";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(['amcname' => $cname, 'amccode' => $ccode, 'amcregno' => $cregno, 'amcvatno' => $cvatno]);
            return true;
        };   
    }
```

:( still having a problem...

Comment: The option is two, if fields into db is unique you can use `INSERT IGNORE` directly into query or you can query a `SELECT` before your insert with a simple `if($result->num_rows === 0) {do you query insert}`

Comment: @Simone Rossaini thanks will try that

Comment: "Still having a problem" means what? That code you've added is for mysqli, and you're using PDO in your question, so you need to change the new code to use PDO because you can't use mysqli functions on a PDO connection.

Comment: @droopsnoot: shot noted, will try

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead:

```
public function insert($cname, $ccode, $cregno, $cvatno) {

  $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(cname) as countname FROM tbl_client WHERE cname = ?");
  $query->bind_param('s',$cname);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->get_result();
  $count = $result->fetch_assoc()['countname']; //count will > 0 if exist in db.
  if ($count === 0) {
    //query insert
  }

}
```

Rememeber to prepare always the query.

Comment: this doesnt do anything also doesnt allow the insert.

Comment: The part I wrote allows you to have the row number from the select query, if the number is 0 then not present in the database executes the insert query. (which I didn't write in my example since you don't have to copy and paste but you have to think, just replace `//query insert` with query)

Comment: Note that the OP is using PDO rather than mysqli as this answer uses.

Answer (score -1):

your question not so clear, if you want to check that the record not exist and then going to insert it , your code must do this, it may you have problem in this part

```
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

if you use PDO use

```
$count = $result->rowCount;
```

so, also you can do it in more better way using replace, if you want to delete old record and insert new one
[REPLACE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)
Or, you can update if record exist
[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)